# Foursquare mayorship api result

Tags: foursquare

1.I need to know more about the foursquare mayor apis. Is it returning a user's particular day's mayorship details? How can i get the user's current venue details in which the user is the mayor of that venue?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [venues detail](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) call and look at the `mayor` field that's returned. This will be the current mayor of the venue.